# How to directly "assign" a process to a semaphore using windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, process

I'm using the following code from Microsoft as a template:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SEM_COUNT 10
#define THREADCOUNT 12

HANDLE ghSemaphore;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID );

int main( void )
{
    HANDLE aThread[THREADCOUNT];
    DWORD ThreadID;
    int i;

    // Create a semaphore with initial and max counts of MAX_SEM_COUNT

    ghSemaphore = CreateSemaphore( 
        NULL,           // default security attributes
        MAX_SEM_COUNT,  // initial count
        MAX_SEM_COUNT,  // maximum count
        NULL);          // unnamed semaphore

    if (ghSemaphore == NULL) 
    {
        printf("CreateSemaphore error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create worker threads

    for( i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
    {
        aThread[i] = CreateThread( 
                     NULL,       // default security attributes
                     0,          // default stack size
                     (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ThreadProc, 
                     NULL,       // no thread function arguments
                     0,          // default creation flags
                     &ThreadID); // receive thread identifier

        if( aThread[i] == NULL )
        {
            printf("CreateThread error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Wait for all threads to terminate

    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADCOUNT, aThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    // Close thread and semaphore handles

    for( i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
        CloseHandle(aThread[i]);

    CloseHandle(ghSemaphore);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID lpParam )
{

    // lpParam not used in this example
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpParam);

    DWORD dwWaitResult; 
    BOOL bContinue=TRUE;

    while(bContinue)
    {
        // Try to enter the semaphore gate.

        dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject( 
            ghSemaphore,   // handle to semaphore
            0L);           // zero-second time-out interval

        switch (dwWaitResult) 
        { 
            // The semaphore object was signaled.
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
                // TODO: Perform task
                printf("Thread %d: wait succeeded\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
                bContinue=FALSE;            

                // Simulate thread spending time on task
                Sleep(5);

                // Release the semaphore when task is finished

                if (!ReleaseSemaphore( 
                        ghSemaphore,  // handle to semaphore
                        1,            // increase count by one
                        NULL) )       // not interested in previous count
                {
                    printf("ReleaseSemaphore error: %d\n", GetLastError());
                }
                break; 

            // The semaphore was nonsignaled, so a time-out occurred.
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT: 
                printf("Thread %d: wait timed out\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
                break; 
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

And I want to adapt it so instead of being the threads the ones that determine how the semaphore fills, it's done by processes, meaning that the semaphore will fill if there are processes running and/or with any of their habdles not closes, and indeed I sort of have done it by changing the working of the thread function with this new function.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID lpParam )
{

    // lpParam not used in this example
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpParam);

    DWORD dwWaitResult; 
    BOOL bContinue=TRUE;

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    memset(&si,0,sizeof(si));
    si.cb=sizeof(si);

    while(bContinue)
    {
        // Try to enter the semaphore gate.

        dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject( 
            ghSemaphore,   // handle to semaphore
            0L);           // zero-second time-out interval

        CreateProcess("arbol.exe",NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);    
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

        switch (dwWaitResult) 
        { 
            // The semaphore object was signaled.
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
                // TODO: Perform task
                printf("Thread %d: wait succeeded\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
                bContinue=FALSE;            

                // Simulate thread spending time on task
                Sleep(5);

                // Release the semaphore when task is finished

                if (!ReleaseSemaphore( 
                        ghSemaphore,  // handle to semaphore
                        1,            // increase count by one
                        NULL) )       // not interested in previous count
                {
                    printf("ReleaseSemaphore error: %d\n", GetLastError());
                }
                break; 

            // The semaphore was nonsignaled, so a time-out occurred.
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT: 
                printf("Thread %d: wait timed out\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
                break; 
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

With that, although what determines the filling of the semaphore is the thread, in a practical sense it is determined by the complete execution and closing of the handles of the process.

But this looks as a lame way to solve this problem and I bet doing it this way is likely to give problems in the future if extra things are needed from those processes.

How can I create a semaphore so what would really determine the filling of the semaphore would be the processes? To clarify, this would be one possible solution that I don't think it is possible anyhow.

Let's consider that you could Create a Process by something like this:

```
 aThread[i] = CreateProcess( 
                     NULL,       // default security attributes
                     0,          // default stack size
                     (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ThreadProc, 
                     NULL,       // no thread function arguments
                     0,          // default creation flags
                     &ThreadID); // receive thread identifier
```

Then LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE would be equivalent in its working but for processes.

Semaphores are supposed to support [Interprocess Synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms684123(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows API, but I cannot find any example that specifically uses processes, and I don't get the idea of how could it be done.

Any idea on how to achieve what I want?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You want a named semaphore. Where each process shares the semaphore by creating it with the same name.

Create a named semaphore.  Same as you have before, but that last parameter gets a string passed to it:

```
HANDLE hSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 
                                    MAX_SEM_COUNT,
                                    MAX_SEM_COUNT,
                                    L"TheSemaphoreForMyApp");
```

Child processes, upon being started, can attach to that same semaphore and get a handle to it by using [OpenSemaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684326(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
HANDLE hSemaphore = OpenSemaphore(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, 
                                  FALSE,
                                  L"TheSemaphoreForMyApp");
```

You don't have to hardcode a string as the semaphore name. The parent process can create a unique name each time, and then passes that name (e.g. command line parameter) to the child process.  That will allow for multiple instances of your program with child processes to cooperate.